# Receiving JSON from PHP to Angular 2 httpmodule

Tags: php, json, post, angular, httpmodule

Using PHP I am echoing a response from SQL Server by using:

```
echo json_encode($total);
```

Just as a test, before I echo, I run error_log(json_encode($total)) which outputs the object as:

```
[{"address":"Mitchell Hwy",
  "description":"Nyngan Eastbound STC",
  "site_name":"T0242",
  "heading":"East",
  "vehicle_class":"B double",
  "vehicle_class_id":"10",
  "avg_speed":"69.27",
  "volume":"46"}]
```

Which is exactly what I want to receive within Angular 2's http response.  My Angular 2 code is:

```
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(url, sentArray,{
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe(
      result => returnedJSON = result,
      () => console.log("Failed..."),
      () => console.log(returnedJSON)
    );
```

This prints a 'Response' object in the console, where the Response 'body' is the returned PHP code that I want.

```
Response {_body: "[{"address":"Mitchell Hwy","description":"Nyngan E…_id":"Total","avg_speed":"67.35","volume":"262"}]", 
status: 200, 
ok: true, 
statusText: "OK", 
headers: Headers…}
```

My questions are:
Why am I receiving an entire response object?  Is this because I used POST HTTP request - or just the way the Angular 2 receives the response?  How do I isolate just the Response body?

I assume I am doing everything correctly in PHP since I am logging the exact output that I want.  I assume that this is something to do with my Angular 2 code...

Comment: using `response.json()` in the `subscribe` callback will do the trick.

Comment: Harry Ninh - thank you :)
If you post it as an answer, I will remove my answer and mark yours as correct (if you like).

Comment: It's ok, improve yours and mark it as done. I'm totally fine with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologise - In case anyone else got stuck at the same point, the answer is really simple.  You isolate the response body using '.text()'.  I found this here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html

```
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(url, sentArray,{
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe(
      result => returnedJSON = result.text(), //the '.text()' was the issue.
      () => console.log("Failed..."),
      () => console.log(returnedJSON)
    );
```

**EDIT**

Harry Ninh provided a better solution.  Using 'result.json()' instead of '.text()'.
'Result.json()' returns an object array which was better for me.